# Subroutes in Next Js

Tags: javascript, routes, next.js

I´m new to next js, I have created a file called orders.js under pages directory, and I can access it correctly from localhost:3000/orders.

However, I want now to have a subroute, to access the order with id 1 (for example). So I have created a directory 'orders' inside the directory pages, and renamed order.js to index.js, after that, I have created another file inside the orders directory called id.js.

So my current structure is:

```
pages/
      orders/
             index.js
             id.js
```

However I cannot access to localhost:3000/orders/1.

Using Nuxt js, this was trivial, how can I achieve the same with next.js ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is also trivial with Nextjs, however, you're trying to achieve it the harder way.

Your first approach is correct. If you don't specify a route for your pages in the `server.js` file, Nextjs will automatically use them if the URL is correct (in this case orders leads to the orders.js page).

What you're looking for is to create a custom route. You can see the documentation for this [here](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#custom-server-and-routing)

I find the example in the documentation confusing, so I recommend using express instead. Here's an [example](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/custom-server-express) for that. You can then see the express routes in the `server.js` file of the example.

Your route would end up looking something like this:

```
server.get('/orders/:id', (req, res) => {
  return app.render(req, res, '/orders', req.query)
})
```

Where `:id` is a query param which you can then access in your `getInitialProps` inside your orders.js page.

You can check the express routing examples in the express [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [next-routes](https://github.com/fridays/next-routes), dynamic routes for Next.js

And simply create a routes.js and add,

```
const routes = require('next-routes')
module.exports = routes()
 .add('orders', '/orders/:id', 'orders/id')
// name, url, page folder
```

Or if you only want the server side routing,

```
  server.get('/orders/:id', (req, res) => {
    const actualPage = '/orders' 
    app.render(req, res, actualPage, req.query)
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you : https://nextjs.org/docs#dynamic-routing.

by adding [ ] to a page it creates a dynamic route, in this case [orderid].js can be used to map multiple orders to a single page.

```
pages/
       orders/
              [id].js
```

Answer (score 0):

use

> pages/
>          orders/
>                 [dynamic_subroute].js

now catch it with

> const router = useRoute();
>   const { dynamic_subroute } = router.query;

Now, you can catch the value (any) dynamically from the url which is used instead of `dynamic_subroute`

like- if the url is pages/orders/1
then value of `dynamic_subroute` will be 1 in your page